# How to use following perl one liner for directories and subdirectories for any extension files using perl one liner or find?

Tags: find, sed

---

Here is the line which delete the minimum digit lines from my file when it is in particular directory.My query is to the same code should support for all directories and subdirectories and all extension files not only for .html extension files.How can i do it?

```
perl -e 'print q(<table><tr class="normal">). (sort {$b cmp $a} grep {/rev/i} split /(?:<\/?tr[^>]*>\s*)+/i, join "", <>)[0] .q(</tr></table>)' file1.html > file1_red.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean something like this, but I can not be sure:

```
find some_directory -type f -print0 | xargs --null some_command
```